# Error Number: 1364 on insert to exp_member_data

Tags: members, mysql, member-details

I am working with an add-on that does an insert into a custom member data field and I am getting the following kind of error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1364

Field 'm_field_id_2' doesn't have a default value
```

My EE install is currently at 2.5.2 and it was upgraded from EE 1.6.9. In checking the `exp_member_data` table in database I can see that none of the custom field columns are set up with default values or allowed to be set to NULL. This includes even custom fields I set up after upgrading.

My questions are:

1. Is it default behaviour for EE to create new `exp_member_data` columns to not allow NULL and to have no default set? Seems like it shouldn't be.
2. Did something happen to my `exp_member_data` table in my upgrade so it is not set up correctly for EE2?
3. Am I safe to simply set the columns in the `exp_member_data` table to allow NULLS and set the default value to NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this in my fresh EE 2.5.5 install

```
fiedl:m_field_id_1 type:varchar(100) NULL:YES Default:
```

You can probably safely adjust your columns

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and everything seems to be working fine. I figure when I update to 2.5.5 that will update things as well. Thanks for the reply.